# Django doesn't logout a user

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django

I have a django application that is successfully able to signup and login a user.However I am unable to logout a user.

In the front end, I have a webpage that contains a power button icon, which on clicking should trigger a logout request.

I am using angular js for front end

**index.html**

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
     <span style="opacity: 0.5;font-family: FontAwesome;font-size: 14px;color:#838F98;text-align:center;cursor:pointer" ng-click="logout()">
               <i class="fa fa-power-off" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </span>
</div>
```

Here I use `ngclick` to call the `logout()` function that is defined in my *index.js*

**index.js**

```
$scope.logout = function() {
       var url = '/logout';
       var toSend = {
          username: username_id,
     }
   $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: url,
      data: toSend,
   }).then(function(response) {
     response.data;
   })
  };
```

This function calls the `/logout` url for which I have defined an auth views in urls.py

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout

url(r'^logout$', logout, {'template_name': 'login.html'}),
```

But when I click the power icon on the webpage, nothing happens.The user stays in the page and I don't event get any error message.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Ok I changed the Javascript `POST` call to the `/logout` url to a GET call and it seems to work.However the page doesn't redirect to the `login.html` page and stays on the same page.If I close the tab and reopen it, it asks for login again which means the logout works now.But why doesn't it redirect to the login page and just stays there?

Comment: try debugging in your console .

Comment: Did you by any chance, have overwritten the `logout` procedure (for example importing something with a similar name, or writing a `logout` function in the `views.py`)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem no in my `views.py`, I have defined a `logout_view` as a function for logging out users.Nowhere else in `views.py` file, I have defined any function called `logout`.

Comment: Can you post your console output

Comment: @EmmanuelMtali I posted an update to the question.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem please check the update to the question.

Comment: what about your settings file, did you set the LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL ?

Comment: @matiasm77 oh I did forget to set that.However even then it doesn't redirect.In the inspect element, I see its trying to fetch `/logout` url first which I haven't defined and gives a 302 error.And then it tries to visit '/login' url. But I anyway don't want it to visit '/logout' url.I just want it to be redirected to the login page url which is '/login' and this I have set as the LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL value.

Answer (score 0):

From a simple research i found that you need to redirect the the page using javascript afrer you have received your response.

In your case

```
$scope.logout = function() {
    var url = '/logout';
    var toSend = {
        username: username_id,
    }
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: toSend,
    }).then(function(response) {
        // perform redirect
        window.location('/login');
    })
};
```

Comment: hey thanks for your response.But if you observe my `urls.py`, I have used django's auth views logout.

Comment: What version of django are you using?

Comment: my version is django 1.10